# cannot access class in the same package without adding to classpath

Tags: java, tomcat

Project structure:

```
./src/com/example/Test.java
./src/com/example/Dog.java
```

Test.java

```
package com.example;

public class Test {
    public void testing() {
        Dog d = new Dog("Lab");
    }

}
```

Dog.java

```
package com.example;

public class Dog {
    private String breed;

    Dog(String breed) {
        this.breed = breed;
    }
}
```

It compiles successfully when I try this

`.\src > javac com\example\Test.java`

But it fails when I do this

`.\src > javac -cp "C:\Tomcat\lib\servlet-api.jar" com\example\Test.java`

With this error

```
error: cannot find symbol
                Dog d = new Dog("Lab");
                ^
  symbol:   class Dog
  location: class Test
```

I'm guessing it's because the existing classpath is overwritten. How do I avoid that?

Also, can you explain more on detail why it fails when it is run from the parent directory of \src, like this

`javac src\com\example\Test.java`

I get the same error as the one with classpath.

Sorry for all the confusion.

Thank you Jon Skeet for helping out.

Comment: I suggest you rewrite this as a [mcve] which only has `Test.java` and `Dog.java` - the servlet part is almost certainly a red herring.

Comment: I can't reproduce this error, having put the `src` directory in the classpath. Are you certain that `"C:\Users\AK051428\Desktop\projects\listener_test\src"` is the same as just `src`? Why not just specify it as `src`?

Comment: @JonSkeet I have tried to make it minima and concise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler will treat directories on the classpath as source root directories - in other words, when trying to find classes for package `com.example`, it will look for both class *and source* files in a `com/example` subdirectory from each directory on the classpath.

When you compile like this:

```
.\src > javac com\example\Test.java
```

... the classpath is implicitly "the current directory".

When you specify the classpath explicitly like this:

```
.\src > javac -cp "C:\Tomcat\lib\servlet-api.jar" com\example\Test.java
```

... it isn't. You'd need to add `.` to the classpath explicitly:

```
.\src > javac -cp "C:\Tomcat\lib\servlet-api.jar";. com\example\Test.java
```

Similarly when you're not *in* `src`, you'd have to specify `src` as being on the classpath:

```
. > javac -cp src src\com\example\Test.java
```

Personally I try to make sure that all the sources I want to compile are explicitly listed in `javac` anyway - otherwise it's quite possible to use out-of-date class files rather than recompiling the source code.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Just to make sure I understand the last part, when i say just `. > javac src\com\example\Test.java` without classpath, it looks for the Dog.java in .\com\example and not in .\src\com\example, right?

Comment: and thank you so much for being so patient and helpful. You're a good man :D

Answer (score 0):

One more possible solution:

`javac -cp C:\Tomcat\lib\servlet-api.jar -sourcepath C:\Users\AK051428\Desktop\projects\listener_test\src -d classes src\com\example\TestServlet.java`

This now tells javac where your source tree is located.

Comment: adding src to sourcepath or classpath does that trick, but I want to know why it doesn't work without that.

Answer (score -1):

```
.\listener_test > javac -cp .;C:\Tomcat\lib\servlet-api.jar;"C:\Users\AK051428\Desktop\projects\listener_test\src" -d classes src\com\example\TestServlet.java
```

Add ".; "